# Video not playing in Safari iOS, but will play in Chrome

Tags: ios, iphone, video, html5-video, mobile-safari

I have a HTML video tag that I just cannot get playing in Safari iOS. The video works fine in my mobile Chrome browser and I really can't figure out why. My code for the video is:

```
<div class="slider-video">
    <video preload="auto" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
        <source src="my_video_src" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>
```

My video source is being pulled from a Vimeo video file. I have tried adding the '`controls`' attribute with no change. I know Safari on iPhone can be temperamental when it comes to playing video but I wondered if anyone could maybe suggest something I might have missed.

Comment: Can you share a link to the video or the console output from Safari?

Answer (score 0):

If you press play on the controls and it still doesn't work then it's likely incompatible, either because of a corruption or because of encoding settings. It surprises me that something coming out of Vimeo wouldn't work, but you probably need to transcode it again to something iPhones support.